# Excel VBA Macro - How to grab Median and Average of column and print out results

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to look up a column name "total cycle time" then at the very end of the column I would like the average and then a line below that the median of the entire column.

Below is a start but it seems to only pull from one table hence the Table14 reference. I don't understand how to state look at only this active sheet.

```
Sub Macro10()
'
' Macro10 Macro
'
Range("U" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=AVERAGE(Table14[[#Headers],[#Data],[Total Cycle Time]])"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=MEDIAN(Table14[[#Headers],[#Data],[Total Cycle Time]])"

'
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say that somewhere in the worksheet we have a header cell with data below it like:

[image]

Running this short macro will:

1.locate the header and associated column of data
2. put the desired statistics in the cells below the values

```
Sub SaveStats()
    Dim header As Range, DataRange As Range

    Set header = Cells.Find(What:="total cycle time", after:=Cells(1, 1))
    Set DataRange = Range(header, Cells(Rows.Count, header.Column).End(xlUp))

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        Cells(DataRange.Rows.Count + DataRange.Row, DataRange.Column).Value = .Average(DataRange)
        Cells(DataRange.Rows.Count + DataRange.Row + 1, DataRange.Column).Value = .Median(DataRange)
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

**NOTE:**

The macro has no error handling.  It will die if there is no data below the header.

Comment: im getting an immediate error with Sub SaveStats()

Ambiguous name detected: SaveStats

Comment: @JoBe  am not sure.  I only ran some simple tests.

Comment: first line "Sub SaveStats()"

Comment: @JoBe  Just change the name................it is conflicting with an old macro..............

Comment: my bad i did not remove the generic "sub Macro #"

Comment: This worked. Thanks! 

I did not think to create sets. I will have read up on this to up my Macro game

Comment: I don't understand why your answer was downvoted as you answered everything correctly.

Comment: @JoBe  Perhaps because the macro has no error handling.............it will die if there is no data below the header!